# Dotnet Core 5.0 - Entity framework - Design time migration works but getting errors on completion

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My solution has a web project with a number of libraries. The designtime factory class file called "Migrations.cs" is in the web project JobsLedger.API and the DbContext class is in the JobsLedger.TENANTS library.

The designtime factory class is as follows:

```
namespace JobsLedger.API 
{
    public class DesignTimeTENANTSContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TENANTSContext> 
    {
        public TENANTSContext CreateDbContext(string[] args) 
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TENANTSContext>();

            var connectionString =  configuration.GetConnectionString("CatalogConnection");
    
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new TENANTSContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

My DbContext class is as follows:

```
namespace JobsLedger.TENANTS
{
    public class TENANTSContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

        // Constructors..
        public TENANTSContext(DbContextOptions<TENANTSContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public TENANTSContext(DbContextOptions<TENANTSContext> options, HttpContext httpContext) : base(options)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContext;
        }
        .....
```

I run the migration in powershell with the following:

```
dotnet ef migrations add INITIAL --context TENANTSContext -s ../Jobsledger.API
```

It works but with a large number of errors.. see the following:

> PS C:\Users\Simon\Documents\AURELIA\1.2 - JOBSLEDGERSPA ODATA
> NEW\JobsLedger.TENANTS> dotnet ef migrations add INITIAL --context
> TENANTSContext -s ../Jobsledger.API Build started... Build succeeded.
> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
> services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATABASE.CREATION.SERVICE.Interfaces.INewDatabaseService
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATABASE.CREATION.SERVICE.NewDatabaseService': Unable to
> resolve service for type
> 'JobsLedger.TENANTS.Repositories.Interfaces.IAccountTENANTSRepository'
> while attempting to activate
> 'JobsLedger.DATABASE.CREATION.SERVICE.NewDatabaseService'.) (Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATABASE.CREATION.SERVICE.Interfaces.ITenantAndAccountInitialisations
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATABASE.CREATION.SERVICE.TenantAndAccountInitialisations':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'JobsLedger.TENANTS.Repositories.Interfaces.IAccountTENANTSRepository'
> while attempting to activate
> 'JobsLedger.DATABASE.CREATION.SERVICE.TenantAndAccountInitialisations'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext': No constructor for type
> 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services from
> the service container and default values.) (Error while validating the
> service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.IBrandDATARepository Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.BrandDATARepository': No constructor for
> type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services
> from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.IClientDATARepository
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.ClientDATARepository': No constructor for
> type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services
> from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.ICounterDATARepository
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.CounterDATARepository': No constructor
> for type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using
> services from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.IJobDATARepository Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.JobDATARepository': No constructor for
> type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services
> from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.ILoggingDATARepository
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.LoggingDATARepository': No constructor
> for type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using
> services from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.INoteDATARepository Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.NoteDATARepository': No constructor for
> type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services
> from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.INoteTypeDATARepository
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.NoteTypeDATARepository': No constructor
> for type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using
> services from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.IStateDATARepository Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.StateDATARepository': No constructor for
> type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services
> from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.IStatusDATARepository
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.StatusDATARepository': No constructor for
> type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services
> from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.ISuburbDATARepository
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.SuburbDATARepository': No constructor for
> type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services
> from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.ITypeDATARepository Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.TypeDATARepository': No constructor for
> type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services
> from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces.IVisitDATARepository Lifetime:
> Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.VisitDATARepository': No constructor for
> type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated using services
> from the service container and default values.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.API.App.ClientService.Interfaces.IClientServices
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.API.App.ClientService.ClientServices':
> No constructor for type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be
> instantiated using services from the service container and default
> values.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.API.App.JobService.Interfaces.IJobServices
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.API.App.JobService.JobServices': No
> constructor for type 'JobsLedger.DATA.DATAContext' can be instantiated
> using services from the service container and default values.) (Error
> while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.Authorisation.Interfaces.IAccountService
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.Authorisation.AccountService':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'JobsLedger.TENANTS.Repositories.Interfaces.IAccountTENANTSRepository'
> while attempting to activate
> 'JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.Authorisation.AccountService'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.Common.Interfaces.IAddressDropdownServices
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.Common.AddressDropdownServices':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'JobsLedger.INTERFACES.IUserSession' while attempting to activate
> 'JobsLedger.API.CONTROLLER.SERVICES.Common.AddressDropdownServices'.)
> (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> JobsLedger.DATABASE.CREATION.SERVICE.Interfaces.ITenantAndAccountInitialisations
> Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
> JobsLedger.DATABASE.CREATION.SERVICE.TenantAndAccountInitialisations':
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'JobsLedger.TENANTS.Repositories.Interfaces.IAccountTENANTSRepository'
> while attempting to activate
> 'JobsLedger.DATABASE.CREATION.SERVICE.TenantAndAccountInitialisations'.)
>
> Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'

Why? How do I fix this?

It seems to be trying to create services from startup.. I would have thought it didnt need to as I was using a factory..

Comment: Seems this one is too hard...